# Unable to load certificate .pem

Tags: debian, ssl, кодировка, openssl, x509certificate

Собственно, вот такая ошибка:

```
/ssl openssl x509 -inform der -in site_ru.crt -out site_ru.pem
unable to load certificate
140451851716160:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1130:
140451851716160:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:290:Type=X509
```

Никаких лишних символов нет, ни в начале, ни в конце:

```
/ssl xxd -l 10 site_ru.crt
00000000: 2d2d 2d2d 2d42 4547 494e                 -----BEGIN
```

Comment: Все хорошо, спасибо. Действительно, забыли добавить ключ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Расширения файла X509
>
> ```
> .DER – расширение .DER примеяется к двоичным файлам сертификатов. Такие файлы так же могут иметь расширение .CER или .CRT. 
> .PEM – используется для различных типов файлов X.509v3, которые содержат данные в виде ASCII (Base64), и начинаются со строки — BEGIN.
> ```
>
> Распространенные расширения файлов
>
> ```
> .CRT – расширение для файлов сертификатов. Сам сертификат может быть бинарным файлом .DER или ASCII – .PEM. Расширения .CER и .CRT фактически являются синонимами. Наиболее часто встречаются в UNIX-системах.
> .CER – альтернативная форма .CRT у Microsoft.
> .KEY – это расширение используется для публичных и приватных ключей PKCS8, которые могут храниться в бинарном .DER или ASCII .PEM формате.
> ```

[Источник](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them), [на русском](https://rtfm.co.ua/tlsssl-der-vs-pem-tipy-fajlov-i-ix-konvertaciya/)

Вероятно ваш сертификат не в кодировке DER попробуйте выполнить команду

```
openssl x509 -inform pem -in site_ru.crt -out site_ru.pem
```

Вы так же можете просмотреть сведения о вашем сертификате командой

```
openssl x509 -in site_ru.crt -text
```

Comment: Получилось сделать:
`openssl x509 -inform pem -in site_ru.crt -out site_ru.pem`

но ошибка Apache:

`Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`
error_log:
`[Fri Dec 28 15:04:59.020414 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 22187] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
[Fri Dec 28 15:04:59.020417 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 22187] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key sheerdecor.ru:443:0, check /ssl/site_ru.pem
AH00016: Configuration Failed`

Comment: А ключ в вашем конфиге есть? эта опция сертификат-  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/site_ru.crt, а эта ключ - SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/site_ru.key